# WSO2 data services server. Is it possible that a query can have sort of "dynamic data source"

Tags: wso2

I am using data services server. Is it possible that a query can have sort of "dynamic data source" ? Because our company have multiple database , so the same query have to create one time for each database.

***Below, data source is fixed:***

[image]

Comment: I believev you have statically refer a datasource from queries. However you could use 'nested queries' to invoke multiple queries and aggregate the results

Comment: I think 'nested queries' is not what I nedd. If the query is the same, and I have 3 different databases, then I must implement 3 different queries. I hope I can just implement 1 query.